# Android app to connect to backend database / website

Tags: android, database

I want to setup an Android app that will connect to a backend database (web/database server that I maintain).  What are some good resources for doing so?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Watch Virgil Dobjanschi's Google I/O talk: [Android REST client applications](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xHXn3Kg2IQE).

He goes over a good pattern to use when dealing with a web service of any kind.  His example uses REST, but you could just as easily apply this to SOAP or anything else you need.